# I can't seem to get my contact form to send all the info

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So this is the code i have in the controller:

```
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ContactModel c)
    {
        //make sure the data is valid
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(
                    "dummyemail",//from email
                    "dummyemail",//to email 
                    "Message from your site-" + c.Subject,//subject of email
                    string.Format("Name:{0}<br/>Desired Method of Contact:{1}<br/>Contact Info:{2}<br/>Message:{3}", c.Name, c.ContactInfo, c.Address, c.Message)
                    );//end mailmessage msg
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                //sends the email 
                using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.secureserver.net"))
                {
                    client.Send(msg);
                }//end using statement to avoid opening and closing the connection strings

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }//end if modelstate is valid
        return View(c);
```

And this is what I have on the page:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <h4>Contact me by E-Mail</h4>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactInfo, "Phone Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactInfo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactInfo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, "Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactInfo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, "Type of Service", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, "Comments", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }@*end using(htmlbeginform())*@
```

And this is my model:

```
    public class ContactModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }//this will be the customer's name.

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone")]
    [DisplayName("Phone")]
    public string ContactInfo { get; set; }//this will be either an email or a phone number.

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an address")]
    [DisplayName("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }//can be left blank, we'll fill it in anyways.

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your message")]
    [UIHint("MultiLineText")]//used with the .editorfor on the view - - - causes the textbox to be a textarea instead
    public string Message { get; set; }
}//end class
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why when the email's get sent they contain everything but the message part of it. the multiline, the important part where clients will let us know what they need. Assistance would be much appreciated from OP.

Comment: Not clear what you asking. Are you saying that if the user leaves the textarea for `Message` blank, then `ModelState` is valid?

Comment: When the user fills out the forms (all of them) the message gets sent, but the text put inside of the `Message` gets cut off and isn't sent in the email :/